# Hive-MetaStore issue during updating table partitions

Tags: java, hive, hive-metastore

I am trying to update hive-table partitions using Hive Java Api's.These are the below steps that i am following to achieve this:-

1.Extracting partitions which are not in metastore.
2.Adding these Partitions to table.
3.Going back to Hive-Command line and running show partitions and msck repair table command just to make sure everything is fine.

What i got:-
1.Show partitions is working fine(giving list of partitions which i have added).
2.MSCK Repair command is not working(getting this :Partitions are not present in metastore.)

Here is the piece of code that i am using :-

```
public class HiveMetastoreChecker {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String dbName = "db_name";
    final String tableName = "db_name.table_name";

    CheckResult result = new CheckResult();
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        HiveConf conf = new HiveConf();
        conf.addResource(configuration);
        Hive hive = Hive.get(conf, true);
        HiveMetaStoreChecker checker = new HiveMetaStoreChecker(hive);

        Table table = new Table(dbName, tableName);

        table.setDbName(dbName);
        table.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        table.setOutputFormatClass(HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat.class);

        table = hive.getTable(dbName, tableName);

        checker.checkMetastore(dbName, tableName, null, result);
        System.out.println(table.getDataLocation());
        List<CheckResult.PartitionResult> partitionNotInMs = result.getPartitionsNotInMs();
        System.out.println("not in ms " + partitionNotInMs.size());
        List<org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Partition> partitions = hive.getPartitions(table);

        System.out.println("partitions size " + partitions.size());
        AddPartitionDesc apd = new AddPartitionDesc(table.getDbName(), table.getTableName(), false);

        List<String> finalListOfPartitionsNotInMs = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (CheckResult.PartitionResult part : partitionNotInMs){
            if(!finalListOfPartitionsNotInMs.contains(part.getPartitionName().replace("/",""))){
                finalListOfPartitionsNotInMs.add(part.getPartitionName().replace("/",""));
            }
        }

        for (String partition:finalListOfPartitionsNotInMs) {

            apd.addPartition(Warehouse.makeSpecFromName(partition), table.getDataLocation().toString());
        }
       hive.createPartitions(apd);
    } catch (HiveException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MetaException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MSCK REPAIR is failing on HIVE? If yes then check if the Partition Column name is in CAPITAL Letters. I found the same issue where my PARTITION on aws s3 was like DCA=1000.

If that is the case then execute MSCK REPAIR using Spark SQL and it will owrk, in case you don't want to rename the partition into lower case.